# Castle 2.5/NHibernate/Magnum/NServiceBus

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nservicebus, castle, rhino-security

Is there anyone out there having a working Castle 2.5 based stack including NHibernate (2.1.2.x), FluentNHibernate, Magnum, NServiceBus, rRhino.Security

up and running built for .Net 4?

thanks in advance & greetings,

chris

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [horn](http://github.com/dagda1/horn_src) to build your stack. All of those projects have [available descriptors](http://github.com/dagda1/hornget), you just need to modify them to get the versions you want with the target you want.